# Strange error when dismissing MFMailComposeViewController: error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file

Tags: objective-c, ios, modalviewcontroller, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller, nserror

I am getting a really weird error MFMailCompseViewController. The error is "error: address doesn't contain a section that points to a section in a object file". The app crashes after MFMailCompseViewController dismisses and the email actually get sent.

This is specific to MFMailComposeViewController as I have tried to present a plain view controller modally and it dismisses fine.

Here is the code I wrote to calland present mail composer:

```
- (void) emailImage:(UIImage *)img {
//verified that the image is being returned correctly
UIImage *img1 = [[_delegate photoBrowser:self photoAtIndex:0] underlyingImage];

MFMailComposeViewController *mfViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mfViewController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

NSString *subject = @"Check out this photo I took - Cap That App";

[mfViewController setSubject:subject];
NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img1, 1.0);
[mfViewController addAttachmentData:imgData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"photo.jpg"];

NSString *contactMessage = @"\n\n<a href=\"http://www.agilerocket.com\">Sent via Cap That - Available in the Apple App Store</a>";

[mfViewController setMessageBody:contactMessage isHTML:YES];

[self presentViewController:mfViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

}

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error {
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Status:" message:@"" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];

switch (result) {
    case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
        alert.message = @"You chose not to send the email.";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
        alert.message = @"Your email was saved as a draft. It has not been sent yet.";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultSent:
        alert.message = @"Your email has been sent!";
        break;
    case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
        alert.message = @"There was an error sending the email. Please verify your email is working and try again.";
        break;
    default:
        alert.message = @"You chose not to send the email.";
        break;
}

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^(void) {
    [alert show];
}];
```

}

Thanks in advance for anyone's help on this.

Comment: That looks like a failure in GDB/LLDB, not the underlying error. What's wrong with simply showing the alert immediately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm getting the same error in my app, acting on a tap gesture on a HUD.  My gesture recognizer method is using a block property on the HUD to perform the needful actions, and there's where it's crashing (the code within the block never gets to run).  Apparently the program cannot access that code, and since you also have a completion block that might be a clue to what's happening.

I don't see that I'm doing anything wrong in my code, and you don't seem to be doing that either, so maybe it's a bug.  Are you by any chance running a developer preview of Xcode (4.4 or 4.5)?

**Edit:** it turns out my problem was that the code block property was being released before it got the chance to run.  I think a similar thing might happend in your case, with the alert var.  Can you try moving the alert init within the completion block?

**Edit 2:** As an alternative, try prefixing the alert init with `__weak` (or `__unsafe_unretained` if you're targetting iOS 4.3), that should do it.  If you're not using ARC, use `__block` instead.

Comment: Block properties should be `copy`, not `retain` or `strong`.

Comment: @tc.: yes, it turned out the block property was `assign` in the framework I was using; changed it to `copy` and everything works great now.